# Reading huge CSV files in c

Tags: c, file, csv

I'm trying to read double data from .csv files through a function that I created in C.
 I have tested the program with many files and up untill 100000000 rows and 20 columns (file size about 14.5 GB) I haven’t had  any problems, but if I insert a larger file with 200000000 rows and 20 columns for example, I get a  segmentation fault.
 I’m running the program in a system which has 52 GB of memory, so it's big enough for these files. 
For the compilation I use:
 gcc read_files.c -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
 also before the execution I used ulimit -a unlimited.

The code is:

```
double** file_read(char *filename,int  *numObjs,int  *numCoords,int line_length, int lines_to_skip,int attr_to_skip) 
{
    double **objects;
    long int     i, j, len;
    ssize_t numBytesRead;
    int done=0; 
    FILE *infile;
    char *line, *ret;
    char * pch;

    if ((infile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: no such file (%s)\n", filename);
            return NULL;
    }

    line = (char*) malloc(line_length);

    len = (*numObjs) * (*numCoords);

    objects    = (double**)malloc((*numObjs) * sizeof(double*));
    objects[0] = (double*) malloc(len * sizeof(double));
    for (i=1; i<(*numObjs); i++)
        objects[i] = objects[i-1] + (*numCoords);

    for(i=0;i<lines_to_skip;i++)
       fgets(line, line_length, infile);

    i=0;
    j=0;

    while (fgets(line, line_length, infile) != NULL && i<*numObjs ) 
    {     
             pch=strtok(line, ",;");
             while (pch != NULL && j<(*numCoords))
             {
                objects[i][j]=atof(pch);
                pch = strtok (NULL, ",;");
                j++;
             }
             i++;
             j=0;
             done=0;
    }


    fclose(infile);
    free(line);


    return objects;
}
```

After many tests, I am sure that the segmentation fault occurs inside the while loop but I can't understand why. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be wise to check the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: You should consider running your program under a memory-use analyzer such as Valgrind (maybe on a smaller file first).  I suspect you'll find that the program uses more memory -- maybe a lot more -- than the file's on-disk representation.  Valgrind will tell you about that, and it will also alert you to any memory leaks that may be affecting you.

Comment: So you don't check if `malloc` returns a valid memory block and now wonder why you code crashes? I refuse to answer such a question.

Comment: Your code is asking for about 32Gb of *contiguous* memory.

Comment: Are you trying to read the entirety of the file into memory? If so why? Is it a requirement, because you could probably chunk it.

Answer (score 3):

You have integer overflow. I presume your `int` must be 32 bits, because you would otherwise not have needed to use

```
long int len;
```

for the memory calculation

```
len = (*numObjs) * (*numCoords);
```

The calculation from the figures you provide is `200000000 * 20 = 4000000000`. That is performed as an `int` calculation (the type of the operands), *before* being assigned to `len`, and the product is out of the range of 32 bit `int`.

You would need to cast one of the operands first:

```
len = (long int)(*numObjs) * (*numCoords);
```

or use `unsigned` types.

Comment: Or better yet, make the arguments being passed `size_t *` as well as defining `len` as `size_t len;`.